# How to password protect folder with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have to updated asp.net webform application to using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity at this point i am stuck at two points

1. How to protect folder (example admin) with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
2. How can i add roles to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

I have spend hours looking for article or videos most of the either point to MVC or ASP.Net Core, while i want to use this in ASP.Net webform application with .Net Framework 4.8.

Any pointer or working example would be great.

In simple old asp.net membership we use to protect folder in web.config but i am not sure how to do same in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity as i have not used this in past.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have everything setup in your project (nuget packages, configuration, etc), you can allow or deny access to a folder by adding a `web.config` into it, for example, in the Secure folder:

```
  <location path=".">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>        
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Of course, you need to assign the `Admin` role to certain users. How this is done in your application is up to you (whether in code, from the UI or even by seeding the Identity datastore manually) but the bottom line is to have the related data in your datastore, for example, having configured Identity with Sql Server:

**AspNetRoles table:**

```
Id                                      Name
8BF52920-A844-40D4-B7A3-8430CA2282CD    Admin
```

**AspNetUserRoles table:**

```
UserId                                  RoleId
8baacab0-c54b-4e2e-9742-cf67fd4de3a3    8BF52920-A844-40D4-B7A3-8430CA2282CD
```

If user with Id `8baacab0-c54b-4e2e-9742-cf67fd4de3a3` logs in, access to `https://localhost:44323/Secure/` is granted.

A very good starting point is to create a new project with authentication set to Individual User Accounts:

[image: Create a new ASP.NET WebForms Application with Identity]